# Appending same div multiple times without reducing performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day all, I'm trying to make a game with jquery where a space-ship will be shooting bullets. All are working fine except when it fires multiple bullets performance gets slower. I understand that it is the problem of jquery `.append()` because I used it to generate bullets when spacebar is pressed. But I can't figure it out how to solve this. These are the codes for bullet generating and animation,

```
function generateBullet(objectid, bulletid, bulletclass, left, top) {
    var objectID = $('#' + objectid);
    var bulletID = bulletid;
    var bulletClass = bulletclass;
    var adjust_left = left;
    var adjust_top = top;
    var objectLeft = objectID.offset().left - adjust_left;
    var objectTop = objectID.offset().top - adjust_top;
    var appendingValue = "<div class="+bulletClass+" id="+bulletID+" style='left: "+objectLeft+"; top: "+objectTop+";'></div>";
    $("#content").append(appendingValue);
}

function animateBullet(bulletid) {
    var bulletID = $("." + bulletid);
    bulletID.each(function() {
        var nowTop = $(this).offset().top;
        $(this).css("top", nowTop - 55);
    });
}
```

If there is any other way to generate bullets then please let me know. Again your help will be much appreciated. Tnx!

Comment: $("#content").html(appendingValue);

Comment: Can you add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423938/ajax-show-mysql-content-once/25424004#25424004

Comment: Consider using the parameters directly instead of creating variables as they are used only once.

Comment: @JqueryKing, I used .html() before but after 1st bullet generate, whole page dissapears. Don't know why.

Comment: Are you removing `bullet divs` from dom when `bullet divs` are no more visible (when `bullet.offset().top < 0`){//bullet no more visible .. remove it } ??

Comment: Can you post how you call generateBullet ? The trick might "batching" the creation of divs, but only adding them once.

Comment: @vikrantsingh, yes I'm removing it after reaching at certain point.

Comment: You should add some more context ,like how and where `animateBullet() ,generateBullet() and removeBullet()` are being called ?

Comment: I second @phtrivier. Try batching the creation and animation of your objects. If there are many of them, try detaching them from the DOM, and reappending all at once. If you're lucky, this will be done without a flicker. If at all possible, when updating for instance, store the current position in an object to avoid reading it from the DOM. Many reads and writes in quick succession will slow you down (unless you read all first, and write all after).

Comment: @wojrze, can u give me a small example in code?